# Php, Why won't in_array on first level of multi-dimensional arrays work?

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, multidimensional-array

Say I have a multi-dimensional array like this,

```
$details = array(
    'fruit' => array(
        'path' => '/tmp/fruit',
        'headers' => array(
            'size',
            'weight',
            'colour')),
    'car' => array(
        'path' => '/tmp/car',
        'headers' => array(
            'model',
            'fuel',
            'colour')),
    'animal' => array(
        'path' => '/tmp/animal',
        'headers' => array(
            'species',
            'sex',
            'locale'));
```

Why won't this work? Lets say the url is example.url/web/page/fruit

```
$uriPath = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);

$base = basename($uriPath);

if(in_array($base, $details)) {
    echo($details[$base]['path']);
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: What is value of  `$base` in this case?

Comment: if the the url is example.url/web/page/fruit then it would be "fruit".
if I echo $base, I get fruit.

Comment: so you should use [array_key_exists()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) instead

Answer (score 1):

`in_array()` checks if required **value** exists in array, while you want to check if given **key** exists in array, use [array_key_exists()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) instead.

```php
if(array_key_exists($base, $details)) {
    echo($details[$base]['path']);
}
```